why is my react native installation not progressing
with blank line next to
npx @react-native-community/cli@latest init AwesomeProject

command
I am not sure about the possible reason of not progressing to next step and I am stuck with this for hours .
Please some tell me the reason of such error.
I tried all commands like npx react-native init firstApp
yet no result

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
